# Getting different result $collection->getData and foreach through $collection

Tags: magento2.2, product-collection

I am facing some weird issue in the magento2 collection.

function to get item collection

```
public function getNewItems()
{
    if ($this->_productsCache === null)
    {
        $items = $this->promoRegistry->getLimits();

        $groups = $items['_groups'];
        unset($items['_groups']);

        if (!$items && !$groups) {
            $this->_productsCache = false;

            return false;
        }

        $allowedSku = array_keys($items);
        foreach ($groups as $rule) {
            $allowedSku = array_merge($allowedSku, $rule['sku']);
        }

        $products = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'small_image', 'status', 'visibility'])
            ->addFieldToFilter('sku', ['in' => $allowedSku])
        ;

        foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
            if (!in_array($product->getTypeId(), $this->_allowedTypes)) {
                $this->promoMessagesHelper->showMessage(__(
                    "We apologize, but products of type <strong>%1</strong> are not supported",
                    $product->getTypeId()
                ));

                $products->removeItemByKey($key);
            }

            if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && (!$product->isInStock() || !$product->isSalable()
                || !$this->promoCartHelper->checkAvailableQty($product, 1))
            ) {
                $this->promoMessagesHelper->addAvailabilityError($product);

                $products->removeItemByKey($key);
            }

            foreach ($product->getProductOptionsCollection() as $option) {
                $option->setProduct($product);
                $product->addOption($option);
            }
        }
        $allowedSku = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", implode(',',$allowedSku)) . "'";
        $products->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(sku,$allowedSku)"));

        if (sizeof($products) > 0) {
            $this->_productsCache = $products;
        }
        else {
            $this->_productsCache = false;
        }
    }

    return $this->_productsCache;
}
```

Here the issue is that when i print collection data it showing in right ordering.
But when i try to render it render in different order.

when `$products->getData`

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 3695
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 1059005
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-01-17 16:06:33
            [updated_at] => 2019-06-26 13:58:53
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 4026
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 1059010
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-01-17 16:13:17
            [updated_at] => 2019-06-26 13:59:55
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 6283
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 1049046
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2019-04-23 13:05:24
            [updated_at] => 2019-06-26 14:02:46
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 3897
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 1059008
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-01-17 16:10:32
            [updated_at] => 2019-06-26 13:59:32
            [is_salable] => 1
        )
)
```

when `foreach` through each item

```
    $products = $block->getItems();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getId().'<br>';
}

4026
3695
3897
6283
```

**Notice ordering of Id Here in foreach printing**

Comment: did you find any solution for this? even I am facing same issue

Comment: yes for now i did it loop through `$collection->getData()` and create object in loop.Not the right way to do

Comment: Thank you for response, even I tried same way. Actually I was using helper object to  get collection. So tried directly with block and it works. However its weird issue!!

Comment: Please post solution if you find any.May many people facing this issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. `$collection->getData()` will give you all the products.
2. `$collection->getItems()` or `foreach($collection as $items){...}` will give you those products which have `is_salable` true.
3. Let us check the above two points practically. I have written a custom script in which both `$collection->getData()` and `$collection->getItems()` are compared. The **collection data** which are not available in **collection items** are separated and exported in CSV. Also separated the available items in another CSV. In the CSVs, **sku** and **is_salable** values will be exported. You can compare both CSV and conclude. Please check the [Git Link](https://gitlab.com/knowledgetransfer/m2customscripts/-/tree/master/ProductCountDiffer)
4. For sort order the collection, you can use `setOrder(...)` or `addAttributeToSort(...)`
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

I did face a similar issue with the Collections.
I fixed it by changing `Collection` to `CollectionFactory`.

Earlier I was using `Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\Collection` in Constructor DI
To fix the issue, I switched to `Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory`

This may be because the Magento2 is loading the collection from the earlier loaded collection and when we use Factory, Magento2 creates a new collection object.